# TSQL How to update column from row in same table?

Tags: sql

Say I have this table schema.

ID
AccNo
Amount

Say I have this data

```
ID     AccNo    Amount
1      1020     100.00
2      2040     50.00
```

How do I write a TSQL update query to update AccNo 1020 amount column with the amount from 2040??

Malcolm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a nested select:

```
UPDATE tablename SET Amount = (
    SELECT Amount FROM tablename WHERE ID = 2 )
WHERE AccNo = 1200
```

Obviously if your condition is different, you'll have to tweak to suit, e.g. if AccNo is unique, you can use that.

Comment: And also what if there is a CustNo column and that has to be included in the where clauses so the they match?? Sorry forgot about these points.